# How can I change global fonts in officer

Tags: r

I am trying to make a word document from R. I use the officer package.

```
doc = docx(title = 'test')
```

When I do this, the standard template is used. Is there a way to change the template inside R? Or do i need to make a template outside R (in word) and then use that?

For example; How do i set the  font in the document to calibri, size=10 ?

Comment: This will not run as the function does not exist. You can read the documentation here: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/word.html#quick-start

Comment: @DavidGohel Sure, `docx()` doesn't exist, and you use `read_docx()` to start a document from the standard template, but that typo doesn't have much to do with his question. I have to say it took me some time to figure out this functionality in your package as well; although the `fp_text()` function is described in your documentation, you have to scroll through many function names, potentially reading a lot of things you don't need to in order to find it. Overall, your package and its documentation are really great, but it would be nice to also see some discussion of this type of formatting 1/2

Comment: in the Word tab of https://davidgohel.github.io/officer 2/2

Comment: @duckmayr you are probably right, would you be ok to write what you think should be written? I would be happy to integrate it!

Comment: @DavidGohel Certainly! I'll see if I can get something to you this weekend, though I have to say that work has limited my time for recreational contributions lately.

Comment: @duckmayr no worry about time, your contribution would be welcome even if in one year! I am also very busy and `officer` work only happens after "work that pay salary" and family ;)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found was to:

1. open word and create a blank document
2. Manually change the font size, font family, font color
3. Save the document
4. go back to R and read the document in as a template document
5. Add unformatted paragraphs

For example:

```
  
patient_name <- "John Doe"

  d1 <- read_docx("your_template.docx") %>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par(format(Sys.Date(),"%m/%d/%Y"))%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par(paste0("Dear ",patient_name,","))%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par("I would like my document to have size 12, times new roman font.")%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par("Sincerely,")%>%
  print(target="mytemplate_formatting.docx")
```

This is what happens without using the template

```
patient_name <- "John Doe"

d2 <- read_docx() %>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par(format(Sys.Date(),"%m/%d/%Y"))%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par(paste0("Dear ",patient_name,","))%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par("I would like my document to have size 12, times new roman font.")%>%
  body_add_par("")%>%
  body_add_par("Sincerely,")%>%
  print(target="default_formatting.docx")
```