# capture.output() and officer package to export console output to ms word

Tags: r, ms-word, officer

I would like to export output from R console to word and get nicely aligned everything like showed in R console.
I have read that I have to create some kind of word template.doc or template.docx to achieve this.
I do not know how to do it and to which elements of this creation of that template I must pay special attention to.

```
library(officer)
library(broom)

set.seed(1000)
my_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2))
) %>% mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))) %>%
mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("Control", "Treatment")))

model3 <- lm(response ~ time * treatment, data = my_data)

docx <- read_docx()

z5 <- capture.output(kableExtra::kable(tidy(model3)))

z5 <- as.data.frame(z5)

docx <- to_docx(docx, z5, "Title 1", "Subtitle 1")

fn <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")

print(docx, fn)
```

gives me firstly this:

[image]

and also secondly this:

[image]

Everything here is misaligned in word and will require a lot of tweaking. I hope this could be avoided and look nicely and straight in word at once. My second question is how to create that temp file called "fn" in my working directory because this is saved and deeply hidden in Local\Temp etc. long file path.
I would be grateful for help and for explaining all the necessary steps involved it that process especially in creating that word template in order not messing anything in my word present settings.

Comment: If you are asking how to create an MS Word template with a monospaced font then this seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432710/how-can-i-change-global-fonts-in-officer) question. Have you tried this approach? Is there a particular reason you want the output to appear as text rather than using any of the [`officer::body_add_*()`](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-word.html) functions for producing nicely formatted tables?

Comment: I am not that advanced in officer so could you please show me based on my reprex how to create nicely formatted table using officer::body_add_*() function ?

Comment: As you don't seem to manipulate existing Word documents, Is there a specific reason to use `officer`? I would guess RMarkdown / Quarto report knitted/rendered as docx is a more common approach.

Comment: I want export that console output directly to word, I do not want use RMarkdown / Quarto as I experienced difficulties to knit it to word many times.

Comment: RMarkdown/Quarto is the way to go.  Given OP's comments, I think this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Identify the root cause problem with RMarkdown/Quarto.  Solve it.  Reduce the workload in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

While following is deviating from `{officer}`, this is how I'd get raw Markdown pipe table (console output of `kableExtra::kable(tidy(model3))` ) and its render to Word / docx with Quarto:

````yaml
---
format: docx
---
```{r}
#| warning: false
#| echo: false
#| output: false

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(broom)

set.seed(1000)
my_data <- rbind(
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Pre", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Control", response = rnorm(100, mean=1)),
  data.frame(time = "Post", treatment = "Treatment", response = rnorm(100, mean=2))
) %>% mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("Pre", "Post"))) %>%
mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("Control", "Treatment")))

model3 <- lm(response ~ time * treatment, data = my_data)
```

```{r}
#| echo: false

knitr::kable(tidy(model3), format = "pipe") |> 
  as.character() |>
  paste0(collapse = "\n") |>
  cat()
```
```{r}
#| label: tbl-pipe
#| tbl-cap: "Rendered pipe format"
#| echo: false

knitr::kable(tidy(model3), format = "pipe")
```
````

Renders as:
[image: Renderd docx]

Comment: Thank you @margusl, it works. For me the way to go is R script but this also works nicely.